# fatfreeframework Routing for frontend and backoffice

Tags: routes, url-routing, fat-free-framework

I would like to configure different routings for frontend and backoffice in the routes.ini file.

Here is what I almost have:

```
[routes]

GET|POST /admin/@controller/@action =@controller->@action
GET|POST /admin/* =Backoffice->main
GET|POST /* =Website->main
```

What I want is:

- any url starting with /admin/... is a backoffice url. This will call the method "main" in the "Backoffice" controller or, if given, call the @controller->@action
- any other url should be managed by the "main" method in the "Website" controller. This controller looks for a matching url in the database and displays its content. Otherwise shows a 404 page.

My problem is, anything goes to Website->main() now, which is wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: maybe think about your routing config once more. a wildcard is usually there to eat up everything in the route you do not care about.

Comment: I know that´s the problem, ikkez. Because the url for the frontend can be anything like /company/sales/our_most_expensive_product or just /here_we_go I think I mus use a wildcard. The only thing which differs frontend and backend is that all backend urls start with an /admin/ and use an controller/action mapping.

Comment: well i think you can define your frontend routes: your example ` /company/sales/our_most_expensive_product` could be `/@category/@subcategory/@product` or `/@module/*`. I'm sure you'll find a way that fit for all ;)

Comment: you could also think about placing additional index.php and htaccess files in a real /admin/ dir. So you could have an extra bootstrap file just for the admin backend.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set a ->beforeroute() function in the controller then use a regex to find if the url has /admin/.